# File name manipulation with shell scripts: changing file extensions

Tags: shell

I need to write a shell script to convert the image format from .png to .tif. The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in `ls *.png`
do
    convert $f $f.tif
done
```

But doing this will append the .tif format to the existing filename. ie if the image is abc.png the $f will have abc.png and after converting the filename becomes abc.png.tif. This is not what I want. I need it to be abc.tif. How do I manipulate $f to remove .png?

Comment: [Dont' parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.png
do
    filename=$(basename "$file")
    filename=${filename%.*}
    convert $file $filename.tif
done
```

A line-by-line walkthrough of how this works:

- `for file in *.png` - you don't need command substitution `ls *.png` to get the list of files with `png` extension. The wildcard `*` will auto-expand in shell to match the list of files in cwd; and in this case the list of files ending in `.png`.
- `filename=$(basename "$file")` - this is only for defensive programming; it gets the actual name of the file
- `filename=${filename%.*}` - this removes the extension from `filename`
- `convert $file $filename.tif` - runs your actual convert command

Comment: Or just: for f in *.png; do convert $f ${f%.png}.tif; done You don't need the basename because you are listing files in current directory.

Comment: @dimir - as mentioned, the `basename` part is only for defensive programming. It makes the code more robust if the `*.png` changes to something like `$(find $PWD -name '*.png')`

Comment: But if he does that, shouldn't it put the result in the subdirectory containing the file being converted, instead of the current directory? Also, if you're using `basename`, why aren't you using its second argument to remove the `.png` suffix?

Comment: Another option arguably less intuitive could be :  for file in *.png
 do
     convert $file ${file%%}.tif
 done